# animation rotating boxes css keyframes

Tags: html, css

The boxes are stacked on top of each other using the `position: absolute` property. When you `hover` over the container they should `rotate` with a `delay` between and have the `border` turn orange to create some sort of effect.
They aren't moving at all however.

```css
.main-animation-box {
  border: solid orange;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 16vw;
  position: absolute;
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-1 {
  animation: box-rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-2 {
  animation: box-rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: 5s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-3 {
  animation: box-rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: 5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-4 {
  animation: box-rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: 5s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-5 {
  animation: box-rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: 5s;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes box-rotate {
  10% {
    border: solid orange;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(720deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="email-sub-box email-left">
  <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-1"></div>
  <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-2"></div>
  <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-3"></div>
  <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-4"></div>
  <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @AmanSharma theres an image of my code, just keyframes and hover: if thats what you mean

Comment: @coldharbour https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

i have changed `animation: box-rotate;` to `animation-name: box-rotate;` and `animation-timing-function: 5s;` to `animation-timing-function: ease-out;`

```css
.main-animation-box {
  border: solid orange;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 16vw;
  position: absolute
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-1 { 
  animation-name: box-rotate;
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate; 
 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-delay: 2s;
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-2 {
   animation-name: box-rotate;
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate; 
 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-delay: 1s;
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-3 {
   animation-name: box-rotate;
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate; 
 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-4 {
   animation-name: box-rotate;
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate; 
 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-delay: 2s;
}

.email-sub-box:hover .main-animation-box-5 {
   animation-name: box-rotate;
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate; 
 animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes box-rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
  

<div class = "email-sub-box email-left">
    <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-1"></div>
    <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-2"></div>
    <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-3"></div>
    <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-4"></div>
    <div class="main-animation-box main-animation-box-5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh man awesome! i think i mistook timing-function for duration, among other things. Cheers man

Comment: @coldharbour also i changed `animation` to `animation-name`